# Livestreaming at near lightspeed

Tags: special-relativity

Please forgive me if this is a stupid question as I have a very rudimentary understanding of physics. 
I was reading about how the large hadron collider speeds up subatomic particles to near lightspeed and that the experimenters need to take the effects of time dilation into account because of this. This got me thinking and I came up with a strange thought experiment. Instead of subatomic particles, imagine we could send something like a small vehicle with a few people in it around the "track" (track seems like an inappropriate word but I'm not sure what it's actually called) at near light speed. So imagine they also have a high def webcam with them in the vehicle and that they wirelessly send a video to be broadcast on the internet. What would we see if we were to watch this video? Would they appear to us as if they were in super slow motion?

Comment: You are very sadistic, the poor people! :) have you ever driven in a circle fast? Now imagine this **very** fast^^
Leave the people out, the webcam can work without them.

Comment: @Franklyn You may be interested in this answer: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/251691/what-the-live-streaming-of-a-time-traveler-will-look-like/252228#252228. Originally I intended it as a reply to Ilja's answer here, but the question was already marked as duplicate by the time I wrote it.

Comment: @Franklyn The answer I wrote actually doesn't fit the geometry in the other question and I had to remove it. Just an observation now: Ilja's answer applies if the track is circular and the receiver for the camera's broadcast is in the center of the track. For other positions of the receiver, for instance when it is close to the track itself, so that the camera periodically  comes toward and goes away from the receiver at relativistic velocity, or if the track is linear, the Doppler effect may compete with or simply mask time dilation, as I tried to explain in the removed answer.

Comment: Thanks. That's very interesting, it will take some time to wrap my head around this.

Answer (score 0):

If the webcam is directed onto a watch, you would see it ticking more slowly.

If the webcam is directed on the outside, you will see the normal speed of happenings, e.g. it would show you the same number of rounds as you have seen by looking at the vehicle.
Only it would have to be a very fast webcam, otherwise you would see less frames per second.

And it probably would have to be a magical webcam, since the usual connection to a WLAN would probably not work. But I'm not sure about the engineering details. (Well, I'm sure it would break from the acceleration, so it has to be magical anyways)

Well, and besides, you would see the world distorted, everything shifted to the forward direction, and brighter there and less bright backwards. Just like the pictures you find on the internet, e.g. [here](http://www.vis.uni-stuttgart.de/~muelleta/GpuRay4D/tutorial_3_scene_objects.bmp)